# Como restaurar ventana Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Tengo problemas para restaurar el órden de las barras de herramientas y elementos del **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate**. Algunos han desaparecido y otros están en diferentes lugares de los que habitualmente (y por defecto) estaban.

¿Hay alguna manera de volver esto a defecto?

Saludos.

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268313/4092887).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la barra de menús, elige `Herramientas`, `Personalizar`.
Se abrirá el cuadro de diálogo Personalizar.
En la pestaña `Comandos`, elige el botón de opción del tipo de elemento que deseas restaurar.
En la lista de ese tipo de elemento, elige el menú o la barra de herramientas que deseas restaurar.
Elige el botón Modificar selección y elige Restablecer en el menú que aparece.

También puedes restablecer todos los menús y barras de herramientas mediante el botón `Restablecer todo`.

Fuente: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wdee4yb6(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 2):

En `VISUAL STUDIO 2013` ve a:

```
WINDOW -> Reset Window Layout
```